# Using one service ($http) on all the controllers

Tags: javascript, angular.js, http, controller, factory-method

I have recently started working on angular.js and I like it. I have decided to use a single controller per view. I use the json data from the backend. As my work is progressing, my codes are getting more verbose and I would like your suggestions on how I can (as a newbie) improve my code. I use the default `$http` service to fetch the JSON in my controller. But I don't want to repeat the same thing on all the other controller.

Can I use services or factories to call `$http` service and use them on all the controllers? At least some suggestions on reducing the number of lines in my code and making it more cleaner is very welcome.

**Dashbord Controller**

```
myApp.controller('KnobController', function($scope) {
    // to give dynamic behaviour for knobs using ng-repeat
    $scope.knobItems = {};
    $scope.knobItems.nums = [{
        knobTitle: "Company Profile",
        knobColor: "#f46607"
    }, {
        knobTitle: "Deals left This Month",
        knobColor: "#ffcc00"
    }, {
        knobTitle: "Pricelist",
        knobColor: "#f40787"
    }, {
        knobTitle: "Pictures",
        knobColor: "#a1b80a"
    }, {
        knobTitle: "Videos",
        knobColor: "#14b9d6"
    }];
});
// controller for knobs end here
myApp.controller('DashController', function($scope, $http, $cookies, $cookieStore) {
    $scope.sideToggle = function() {
        $(function() {
            $(".side-nav li:nth-child(2)").append("<img id='arrowRotate' src='images/prof_arrow1.png' data-swap='images/prof_arrow.png'>");
            $("#arrowRotate").click(function() {
                var _this = $(this);
                var current = _this.attr("src");
                var swap = _this.attr("data-swap");
                _this.attr('src', swap).attr("data-swap", current);
                //toggle li's below
                $(".side-nav li:nth-child(3)").toggle();
                $(".side-nav li:nth-child(4)").toggle();
                $(".side_nav_custom li:nth-child(2) a").toggleClass("orangeSwap");
            });
            // booking section modification
            $(".side-nav li:nth-child(10)").append("<img id='arrowBook' src='images/prof_arrow1.png' data-swap='images/prof_arrow.png'>");
            $("#arrowBook").click(function() {
                var _this = $(this);
                var current = _this.attr("src");
                var swap = _this.attr("data-swap");
                _this.attr('src', swap).attr("data-swap", current);
                //toggle li's below
                $(".side-nav li:nth-child(11)").toggle();
                $(".side_nav_custom li:nth-child(10) a").toggleClass("orangeSwap");
            });
        });
    };
    $scope.sideToggle();
    //line graph for chart.js goes here
    // Chart.js Data
    $scope.homeData = { /* data */
        labels: ["",
            "NOV", "DEC", "JAN", "FEB"
        ],
        datasets: [{
            strokeColor: "rgba(255.255,255,1)",
            pointColor: "rgba(159,209,154,1)",
            pointStrokeColor: "rgba(255,255,255,1.00)",
            data: [4.5, 8.8, 7.5, 9.5, 7.8, 9]
        }, ]
    }

    // Chart.js Options
    var step = 2;
    var max = 10;
    var start = 0;
    $scope.homeOptions = { /* options */
        scaleLabel: "<%= value + ' K ' %>",
        pointDot: false,
        bezierCurve: false,
        scaleOverride: true,
        scaleSteps: 10,
        // scaleStepWidth: Math.ceil(4/2),
        scaleSteps: Math.ceil((max - start) / step),
        scaleStepWidth: step,
        scaleStartValue: start,
        scaleShowGridLines: true,
        scaleGridLineWidth: 0,
        scaleGridLineColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.1)",
        datasetFill: false,
        animation: true,
        animationSteps: 60,
        scaleFontColor: "#ffffff",
        scaleFontSize: 14,
        scaleLineColor: "rgba(255,255,255,1)",
        datasetStrokeWidth: 6,
        responsive: true
    };
    //chart.js for bar graph data
    // Chart.js Data
    $scope.hbarData = { /* data */
        labels: ["J", "F", "M", "A", "M", "J", "J", "A", "S", "O", "N", "D"],
        datasets: [{
            label: "My First dataset",
            fillColor: "rgba(31, 187, 166, 1)",
            // strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.8)",
            highlightFill: "rgba(220,220,220,0.75)",
            data: [50, 60, 55, 80, 60, 80, 60, 50, 70, 60, 80, 60]
        }, ]
    }

    // Chart.js Options
    $scope.hbarOptions = { /* options */
        scaleShowGridLines: false,
        showScale: true,
        scaleShowLabels: true,
        barShowStroke: true,
        scaleFontColor: "#d1d5d9",
        scaleShowLabels: false,
        scaleLineColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0)",
        responsive: true
    };
    $http({
        url: site + '/company/dashboard',
        method: "GET",
        transformRequest: encodeurl,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }
    }).success(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        $scope.count = data.count;
        $scope.reviews = data.reviews;
        $scope.market = data.stastics.market;
        $scope.visits = data.stastics;
        $scope.myData = data;
        $scope.custom = true;
    }).error(function(res) {
        console.log(res);
    });
});
```

**app.js**

```
'use strict';
/**
 * @name servicepriceApp
 * @description
 * # servicepriceApp
 *
 * Main module of the application.
 */
var myApp;
(function() {
    myApp = angular
        .module('servicepriceApp', [
            'ngRoute',
            'ngCookies',
            'knob',
            'raty',
            'tc.chartjs'
        ])
        .config(function($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider
                .when('/signup', {
                    templateUrl: 'views/signup.html',
                    controller: 'SignupController'
                })
                .when('/login', {
                    templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
                    controller: 'LoginController'
                })
                .when('/dashboard', {
                    templateUrl: 'views/dashboard.html',
                    controller: 'DashController'
                })
                .otherwise({
                    redirectTo: '/signup'
                });

        });
})();
```

I was also wondering if it was a good idea to use separate controllers for `knobs` and `sidetoggle`.

Answer (score 1):

To get dashboard data in different controllers you should move your $http service outside controller to factory, then in factory make function to query your server and store json data in object. Next you should include dashboardData factory in controller, or I would suggest to use instead ngRoute, ngRoute on steroid: [ui.router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) and provide data to controller by resolve function: [link](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve).

Code refactoring by ui.router way:

**app.js:**

```
var myApp;
(function() {
    myApp = angular
        .module('servicepriceApp', [
            'ui.router',
            'ngCookies',
            'knob',
            'raty',
            'tc.chartjs'
        ])
        .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
            $stateProvider
                .state('signup', {
                    url: '/signup'
                    templateUrl: 'views/signup.html',
                    controller: 'SignupController'
                })
                .state('login', {
                    url: '/login'
                    templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
                    controller: 'LoginController'
                })
                .state('/dashboard', {
                    templateUrl: 'views/dashboard.html',
                    controller: 'DashController',
                    resolve: {
                      dashboardPromise: [
                        'dashboardData', function(dashboardData) {
                          return dashboardData.getDashboardData();
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                });
             $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('signup');
        });
})();
```

**dashboardData factory** `o` object is for e.g further inject new data.

```
myApp.factory('dashboardData', [
  '$http',
  function($http) {
    var o;
    o = {
      myData: []
    };
    o.getDashboardData = function() {
      return $http({
        url: site + '/company/dashboard',
        method: "GET",
        transformRequest: encodeurl,
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }
      }).success(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        angular.copy(data, o.myData);
      }).error(function(res) {
        console.log(res);
      });
    };
    return o;
  }
]);
```

**Controller** Pass your dashboardData from state provider and then get data from object:

```
// controller for knobs end here
myApp.controller('DashController', function($scope, dashboardData, $cookies, $cookieStore) {

    $scope.count = dashboardData.myData.count;
    $scope.reviews = dashboardData.myData.reviews;
    $scope.market = dashboardData.myData.stastics.market;
    $scope.visits = dashboardData.myData.stastics;
    $scope.myData = dashboardData;
    $scope.custom = true;

    $scope.sideToggle = function() {
        $(function() {
            $(".side-nav li:nth-child(2)").append("<img id='arrowRotate' src='images/prof_arrow1.png' data-swap='images/prof_arrow.png'>");
            $("#arrowRotate").click(function() {
                var _this = $(this);
                var current = _this.attr("src");
                var swap = _this.attr("data-swap");
                _this.attr('src', swap).attr("data-swap", current);
                //toggle li's below
                $(".side-nav li:nth-child(3)").toggle();
                $(".side-nav li:nth-child(4)").toggle();
                $(".side_nav_custom li:nth-child(2) a").toggleClass("orangeSwap");
            });
            // booking section modification
            $(".side-nav li:nth-child(10)").append("<img id='arrowBook' src='images/prof_arrow1.png' data-swap='images/prof_arrow.png'>");
            $("#arrowBook").click(function() {
                var _this = $(this);
                var current = _this.attr("src");
                var swap = _this.attr("data-swap");
                _this.attr('src', swap).attr("data-swap", current);
                //toggle li's below
                $(".side-nav li:nth-child(11)").toggle();
                $(".side_nav_custom li:nth-child(10) a").toggleClass("orangeSwap");
            });
        });
    };
    $scope.sideToggle();
    //line graph for chart.js goes here
    // Chart.js Data
    $scope.homeData = { /* data */
        labels: ["",
            "NOV", "DEC", "JAN", "FEB"
        ],
        datasets: [{
            strokeColor: "rgba(255.255,255,1)",
            pointColor: "rgba(159,209,154,1)",
            pointStrokeColor: "rgba(255,255,255,1.00)",
            data: [4.5, 8.8, 7.5, 9.5, 7.8, 9]
        }, ]
    }

    // Chart.js Options
    var step = 2;
    var max = 10;
    var start = 0;
    $scope.homeOptions = { /* options */
        scaleLabel: "<%= value + ' K ' %>",
        pointDot: false,
        bezierCurve: false,
        scaleOverride: true,
        scaleSteps: 10,
        // scaleStepWidth: Math.ceil(4/2),
        scaleSteps: Math.ceil((max - start) / step),
        scaleStepWidth: step,
        scaleStartValue: start,
        scaleShowGridLines: true,
        scaleGridLineWidth: 0,
        scaleGridLineColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.1)",
        datasetFill: false,
        animation: true,
        animationSteps: 60,
        scaleFontColor: "#ffffff",
        scaleFontSize: 14,
        scaleLineColor: "rgba(255,255,255,1)",
        datasetStrokeWidth: 6,
        responsive: true
    };
    //chart.js for bar graph data
    // Chart.js Data
    $scope.hbarData = { /* data */
        labels: ["J", "F", "M", "A", "M", "J", "J", "A", "S", "O", "N", "D"],
        datasets: [{
            label: "My First dataset",
            fillColor: "rgba(31, 187, 166, 1)",
            // strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.8)",
            highlightFill: "rgba(220,220,220,0.75)",
            data: [50, 60, 55, 80, 60, 80, 60, 50, 70, 60, 80, 60]
        }, ]
    }

    // Chart.js Options
    $scope.hbarOptions = { /* options */
        scaleShowGridLines: false,
        showScale: true,
        scaleShowLabels: true,
        barShowStroke: true,
        scaleFontColor: "#d1d5d9",
        scaleShowLabels: false,
        scaleLineColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0)",
        responsive: true
    };
});
```

I think that knobs and sidetoggle scope funtions should be in the same controllers as the views to which you want provide them, so I would not change it.

Comment: Thanks, this helps a lot. Will go through the link and see how it goes.